# JQuery Append Tag Without Id or Class

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have repetitive **nobr** tags which I can't add ID nor Class.

How do I find a specific **nobr** tag which contains a string of text?

```
<nobr>Due Date</nobr>
<nobr>Test</nobr>
<nobr>Hello</nobr>

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('<nobr>Due Date').append('<span class="ms-formvalidation" title="This is a required field." > *</span>');
});
```

If I simply have:

```
 $("nobr").append("*");
```

Then all nobr will be affected.

Comment: This is really a duplicate of a lot of questions... Try :contains or google "jquery selectors".

Comment: For those wondering wtf nobr is: http://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML/Elements/nobr "Examples: No, really. don't use it."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$('nobr').filter(function() {
  return $(this).text() == 'Due Date';
});
```

Comment: http://jsperf.com/filter-vs-pseudo yours is the most performant of the jQuery solutions +1

Comment: however the more elements I add the closer the two solutions get performance wise. (this and pseudo selector)

Answer (score 2):

http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("nobr:contains('Due Date')").append('<span class="ms-formvalidation" title="This is a required field." > *</span>');
});
```

working example : http://jsfiddle.net/EnigmaMaster/FkZcY/

Answer (score 2):

```
$('nobr').get(1); // get the second one
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the containts pseudo selector like this

```
 $("nobr:contains(Test)").append("*");
```

Here is the documentation: http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/

Comment: Should we answer the questions that are really duplicates and easy to answer (10 times a day the same question anyway) ?

Comment: I would be curious to know which solution is more performant. yours or http://stackoverflow.com/a/10337660/829835

Comment: @dystroy I dunno, I joined not so long ago but even I notice the same questions coming over and over. So I don't know really.

Comment: @rlemon the footprint of mine is smaller but after performance wise it's hard to say as both will iterate over all nobr but the other answer will also do more function call when the CSS pseudo selector will only use the selector engine.

Comment: @dystroy: Why don't you help us out here by, uh, finding something of which we can close this as a duplicate? Also see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/50358/what-is-with-people-who-answer-questions-that-are-known-to-be-dupes

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjavascript%5D+contains You perfectly know this question is always asked again. No need to really search. But some people are here just for the reputation points...

Comment: Ah if only rep was gold then it would matter. The one thing I would say for some duplicates, not all,but some like this one, is that compare to the answers in the other question you posted the asker actually learn a second way to achieve this and as unaware of CSS pseudo selector could not have done the search with the terms you did. Trouble I guess is that there is various level of people asking questions in here and sometimes they don't know what to search for. But I guess that's why we should point them to the right direction instead of jumping on our high horses and critic away.

Answer (score 1):

```
$("nobr").each(function() {
    if( $(this).text() == "hello world" ) {
       // this is the element with the text in it
    }
});
```

i'm no jQuery guy, there might be a better solution.